React-Hook-Form with Zod Validation Requires Optional Field
I am using react-hook-form with Zod for form validation in a React project. I have a form where users can send emails, and selecting recipients is optional. However, even after selecting a recipient, the form still prompts that the email field is required. Here is the relevant code:
Page Component:

'use client'

import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Controller, SubmitHandler, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Select from "react-select";
import { z } from "zod";

interface OptionType {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}

const SingleEmailValidation = z.object({
  email: z.array(z.string()).optional(),
  subject: z.string().nonempty("Subject is required!!!"),
  message: z.string().nonempty("Message is required!!!"),
});

const Page = () => {
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState<OptionType[]>([]);
  const { control, handleSubmit, register, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(SingleEmailValidation),
  });

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<any> = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="p-6 shadow-lg rounded-lg bg-white max-w-4xl mx-auto my-10">
      <div className="mb-6">
        <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">
          Recipients
        </label>
        <Controller
          name="email"
          control={control}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value, ...field } }) => (
            <Select<OptionType, true>
              isMulti
              isSearchable
              options={[{ label: "John Doe (john@example.com)", value: "john@example.com" }]}
              className="basic-multi-select"
              classNamePrefix="select"
              onChange={(selected) => {
                onChange(selected || []);
                setSelectedOptions((selected as any) || []);
              }}
              value={selectedOptions}
              {...field}
            />
          )}
        />
        {errors.email && <p className="text-red-500 text-xs italic">{errors.email.message}</p>}
      </div>
      <div className="mb-6">
        <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="subject">
          Subject
        </label>
        <input
          id="subject"
          {...register("subject")}
          placeholder="Enter the subject"
          className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
        />
        {errors.subject && <p className="text-red-500 text-xs italic">{errors.subject.message}</p>}
      </div>
      <div className="mb-6">
        <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="message">
          Message
        </label>
        <textarea
          id="message"
          {...register("message")}
          placeholder="Type your message here"
          className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
          rows={4}
        />
        {errors.message && <p className="text-red-500 text-xs italic">{errors.message.message}</p>}
      </div>
      <button type="submit" className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
        Send Email
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Page;


Issue:
Despite marking the email field as optional in my Zod schema, the form validation behaves as if it's required. After selecting a user, I'm still prompted that the field is required.
Example Data Passed:
When I select a user, the onChange method updates the state and passes an array to react-hook-form like this:
[
  { "label": "John Doe (john@example.com)", "value": "john@example.com" }
]

How can I fix this issue so that the form correctly recognizes the email field as optional and does not require it if no selection is made?
